# Java I/O errors on Android with Jetty

Tags: java, android, http, jetty

I have four Android phones in an ad-Hoc Wifi network.  Each of these Android phones is running a [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) web server.  Jetty has an app specifically for Android, but I believe that is not what I want, so what I did was actually just download the Jetty JAR, and put it in the build-path of my Android project.  The web server is capable of processing `HTTP GET` and `POST` commands.  The `GET` is used by phones to get files from other phones, and the `POST` is used to post XML commands that essentially command a phone to do something.  This all seems to be working fine.

Now, I'm starting to transfer a lot of files between phones.  More specifically, in my setup, one phone is serving 450 image files that the other three phones are trying to get using the `HTTP GET` commands.  Each phone that is requesting files basically has a list of URLs that it does `GET` on to get files, and there is no delay (like `Thread.sleep`) between when a `GET` ends and the next one is processed.  The reason for stating the point of there being no delay between when the first `GET` ends and the next `GET` starts is that the phone that is serving the 450 files is getting pegged pretty hard by `GET` requests.

I've noticed the following Java I/O errors while doing this:

> 04-17 22:48:59.183: W/System.err(31530): java.io.IOException: Closed
>   04-17 22:48:59.183: W/System.err(31530): at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:152)
>   ...
>   04-17 22:49:36.722: W/System.err(31530): java.lang.IllegalStateException: State==HEADER
>   04-17 22:49:36.722: W/System.err(31530):  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:824)
>   ...

These errors are popping up occasionally while Jetty is trying to serve a specific file but I don't think the error is file specific (i.e. the same errors pop up with different files at different times), and I'm thinking the errors have something to do with the OS not being able to read these files fast enough?

The code I'm using to process execute a `GET` is:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
OutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(getURL));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        bis = new BufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(fullPath);

        bytesRead = bis.read(buf1, 0, bufLen);
        while (bytesRead != -1) {
            outStream.write(buf1, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = bis.read(buf1, 0, bufLen);
        }
}
```

I should add that the errors are on the server side, not the client.

Comment: how many users do you think will read your entire long, bad formatted question?

Comment: You have almost 5000 rep, you could help the guy out with an edit instead of being snarky.

Comment: sure you don't want ijetty? http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/